# how to search through an array of strings in contains() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to put all my strings in an array then see if the jquery selector contains any of these stings, if so, do some code.

create my array:

```
var usa_destinos_direct = ["York-Todos", "York-EWR", "Florida-Fort", "Florida-Todos", "Los Angeles", "Oakland" ];
```

then check it is in the jquery selector:

```
if ($("div.pagetitlebox h1:contains(usa_destinos_direct)")){    
    $("div").css("background", "yellow");
}
```

where am I going wrong?

Comment: :contains Selects all elements that contain the specified text, doesn't take array as a param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery doesn't read `usa_destinos_direct` as a variable, but as the string you want to search in the h1.

You should loop over the destination array instead:

```
usa_destinos_direct.forEach(function (str) {
    if ($("div.pagetitlebox h1:contains(" + str + ")")){
        $("div").css("background", "yellow");
    }
};
```

Comment: I had to add the .length but it worked thanks if ($("div.pagetitlebox h1:contains(" + str + ")").length)

Answer (score 0):

You can map that array to build the desired selector:

```
var containsSelector = usa_destinos_direct.map(d => `h1:contains('${d}')`).join(',');
```

```js
var usa_destinos_direct = ["York-Todos", "York-EWR", "Florida-Fort", "Florida-Todos", "Los Angeles", "Oakland" ];
var containsSelector = usa_destinos_direct.map(d => `h1:contains('${d}')`).join(',');

$(`div.pagetitlebox ${containsSelector}`).css("background", "yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pagetitlebox">
<h1>York-Todos</h1>
<h1>Florida-Fort</h1>
<h1>Venezuela</h1>
</div>
```